# No. of orbits of certain size

Tags: group-theory

Let $U,V$ be subgroups of $G$ and $G/U = \{ g_1 U,...,g_e U \}$, with $U_i = g_i U g_i^{-1}$.

Assertion: The number of $V$-orbits of $G/U$ having cardinality $1 \leq j \leq e$ is $N_j/j$, where $N_j$ designates the number of those $i \in [e]$ s.t. $[V: V \cap U_i] = j$.

Proof: To each $i\in [e]$, associate the index $v(i)=[V : V\cap U_i]$. Then $v(i)$ is the cardinality of the $V$-orbit $\omega_i$ of $g_i U$, because $V \cap U_i = \operatorname{stab}_V(g_i U)$. Therefore, denoting $M_j$ the inverse image of a given $j\in[e]$ by the mapping $v$, the set $\{g_i U \}_{i\in M_j }$ is the union of the $V$-orbits of cardinality $j$ in $G/U$; putting $N_j = \left|\,M_j\right|$, we see now that the total number of these $V$-orbits is $N_j/j$, as expected.

I don't understand the part about the set $\{g_i U\}_i$; its size is $N_j$, yes, but then what? Because its size is $N_j$, the desired result $N_j/j$ follows, but from what do we divide $j$? I mean, we should have $N_j = jx$ from which the assertion follows, but what is this $x$?

Comment: I am unsure exactly what you are asking. You say "its size is $N_j$,yes" and "Because its size is $N_j$ the desired result $N_j/j$ follows". So you seem to have understood the proof. What is it that you do not understand?

Comment: The set $\{ g_i U \}_{i \in M_j}$, what is it? The way I interpret and understand the phrasing of the proof is that is a bunch of cosets whose "indices" map to j. We can set the cardinality of $M_j$ to be $N_j$. How we actually reach the desired conclusion from this is what I don't understand.

(off topic: how do I set my account so I receive emails when my threads are answered?)